# Some mines are printing as 0 for a minesweeper grid layout

Tags: c, arrays, minesweeper

I am a beginner C programmer who has to create the initial grid for a minesweeper game where I have to create 2 grids: the first grid prints dots and asterisks(mines) generated by a random function that picks a number between 0 and 1 for each cell, and the second grid keeps the asterisks the same but replaces the dots with a number that tells you how many mines there are touching that cell.

Right now, I have my conditions to check for all 8 cells around a cell containing a mine to count the number of mines that are surrounding it. However, when I print, not all of the mines are printing as asterisks and some are printing as a number instead, and I'm not sure why.

I have my conditions for printing the second grid as if the cell contains a mine, it will print an asterisk, and for everything else, it will display the number counted by the counter function I set before.

My counter cells are correct, but it's only some of the cells that have mines in them that aren't printing asterisks.
I'm also having trouble printing my dash lines correctly to fit the length of the matrix, and am not sure how to fix it.

Any help that I can get would be greatly appreciated.

An example of what's happening is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKyE.jpg

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lab6.h" //THIS REPLACES <stdlib.h> AND USES A FUNCTION CALLED rand() TO GENERATE # BETWEEN 0-1

#define MAX 100
int m, n; //m rows, n columns
double p;

int main(void) {    
    //GET INPUT
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    do {
    printf("Enter the probability p value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &p);        
    }
    while(p>1 || p<0);

    //PRINT DASHED LINE
    char dash[MAX];
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<m; k++) {
     dash[k] = '-';
     printf("%c", dash[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //PRINT ARRAY W/DOTS
    char array[MAX][MAX];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
         double t=rand();
         if (t<p) {
             array[i][j] = '*';
         }
         else {
             array[i][j] = '.';
         }
         printf("%c ", array[i][j]);
     }
    printf("\n");
    }

    //PRINT DASHED LINE
    for (k=0; k<m; k++) {
     dash[k] = '-';
     printf("%c", dash[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //PRINT ARRAY W/NUMBERS
    int num[MAX][MAX];
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
         if (array[i][j] == '*') {
             num[i-1][j]++; //1 row down, same column
             num[i][j-1]++; //1 column left, same row
             num[i-1][j-1]++; //1 row down, 1 column left
             num[i+1][j]++; //1 row up, same column
             num[i][j+1]++; //1 column right, same row
             num[i+1][j+1]++; //1 row up, 1 column right
             num[i+1][j-1]++; //1 row up, 1 column down
             num[i-1][j+1]++; //1 row down, 1 column right
             num[i][j] = -1; //mine
         }
     }
    }

    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
         if (num[i][j] == -1) {
             printf("* ");
         }
         else {
             printf("%d ", num[i][j]);
         }
     }
    printf("\n");
    }

    //PRINT DASHED LINE
    for (k=0; k<=m; k++) {
     dash[k] = '-';
     printf("%c", dash[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num[i-1][j-1]++;` and the like are breaking the array limits when `i` or `j` are `0`. Similarly `num[i+1][j+1]++;` at the other end of the loops, although they don't break the array bounds because of the generous allocation, but are off the board area. The `-1` ones will result in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Two things I noticed where the values inside of `num` array were never initialized to zero,  so if a value was incremented, it's undefined as to what the starting value was. Second thing there are some edge cases where `num` can be indexed out-of-bounds with a negative value.

Comment: Secondly I would work with the supplied `rand()` until the game is working and replace it if you really think it is inadequate for a minesweeper game.